# Shiny click/brush not working with non-cartesian coordinates?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, coordinate-systems, brush

I am working on a Shiny app that should let a user select geographical data points on a world map generated by ggplot2 (as in [this example](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/plot-interaction-selecting-points.html)).

This works if I use the regular coord_cartesian coordinate system (which distorts the maps) but fails if I use the more appropriate **coord_map** coordinate system. It seems like the click/brush events do not receive the correct coordinates after the projection. Is there any way I can work around or fix this without reverting back to cartesian coordinates?

You can find a working example below:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

map_world <- function(world, mapPoints, xlim, ylim){
  # function to generate ggplot world map
  ggplot() + 
    geom_polygon(data=world, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) +
    geom_point(data=mapPoints, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude), color="red") +
    # coord_map messes up the brush select
     coord_map(xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)
    # coord_cartesian would work but distort the map
    # coord_cartesian(xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)
}

mapPoints <- data.frame(Longitude=c(-103, -108, -130, -120),
                      Latitude=c(52, 40, 45, 54))
world <- map_data("world")

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 6, 
           plotOutput("plot1", height = 300, 
                      click = "plot1_click", brush = "plot1_brush") )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 6, 
           h4("Near points"), verbatimTextOutput("click_info") ),
    column(width = 6, 
           h4("Brushed points"), verbatimTextOutput("brush_info") )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # output world map
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    map_world(world = world, mapPoints = mapPoints, 
              xlim=c(-180,180), ylim=c(-90,90))
  })
  # output clicked points 
  output$click_info <- renderPrint({
    nearPoints(mapPoints, xvar="Longitude", 
                  yvar="Latitude", input$plot1_click)
  })
  # output brushed points 
  output$brush_info <- renderPrint({
    brushedPoints(mapPoints, xvar="Longitude", 
                  yvar="Latitude", input$plot1_brush)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried some solutions using `ggplot` but there is some issue with the scaling that is not being picked up by the `plotOutput` function. In the help page (http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/plotOutput.html), note the following:

> For `plotOutput`, the coordinates will be sent scaled to the data space, if possible. (At the moment, plots generated by base graphics and ggplot2 support this scaling, although plots generated by lattice and others do not.) If scaling is not possible, the raw pixel coordinates will be sent. For `imageOutput`, the coordinates will be sent in raw pixel coordinates.

also,

> With ggplot2 graphics, the code in `renderPlot` should return a ggplot object; if instead the code prints the ggplot2 object with something like `print(p)`, then the coordinates for interactive graphics will not be properly scaled to the data space.

I tried moving the `ggplot` to the server portion of the script, but it didn't work.

My proposed solution, use base graphics:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(maps)
library(mapdata)


mapPoints <- data.frame(Longitude=c(-103, -108, -130, -120),
                        Latitude=c(52, 40, 45, 54))

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 6, 
           plotOutput("plot1", height = 300, 
                      click = "plot1_click", brush = "plot1_brush") )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 6, 
           h4("Near points"), verbatimTextOutput("click_info") ),
    column(width = 6, 
           h4("Brushed points"), verbatimTextOutput("brush_info") )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # output world map
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    map('worldHires')
    points(mapPoints$Longitude, mapPoints$Latitude, 
           col = "red", pch = 16)
  })
  # output clicked points 
  output$click_info <- renderPrint({
    nearPoints(mapPoints, xvar="Longitude", 
               yvar="Latitude", input$plot1_click)
  })
  # output brushed points 
  output$brush_info <- renderPrint({
    brushedPoints(mapPoints, xvar="Longitude", 
                  yvar="Latitude", input$plot1_brush)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! However, ggplot2 allowed me to get the world data just once and it seemed faster to render (this example is something I am including more than once in a larger app).I think base graphics won't let me save the world map layer for later. Can you think of a way I could improve the time it takes to generate the map? Thanks again.

Comment: This is essentially the same as doing the original `ggplot` version without `coord_map`, so you might as well use your original code.

Comment: It actually seems to behave differently. This is what I get with [base](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/14842133/17569676/3b4500d8-5f41-11e6-9358-20d888f6b99c.png) versus with [ggplot2](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/14842133/17569677/3b690bfe-5f41-11e6-900b-f63c6addb410.png) (points are being selected from the brushed region on the map to the right). Base re-scales the axes while ggplot2 doesn't, creating more distortion (I submitted the issue to the shiny team at github earlier today).

Comment: Hi @MarianaOliveira, one way I think you can improve speed is using a lower resolution map, i.e. `map('world')` (from the map package) instead of `map('worldHires')` (from mapdata package). Also, the `map` function accepts a `resolution` argument, or you could supply your own polygons to `map` in the `database` argument. I Hope this helps, but I'm still puzzled by ggplot's behavior. Finally, for interactive maps maybe take a look at other options like leaflet.

Comment: Thanks, these are useful suggestions! I had taken a look at leaflet but it seemed like it would be harder to let a user select a geographical region of interest there (I don't think it has a brush option, does it?). You can take a look at the [issue](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1280) I raised on github regarding the ggplot2 behaviour (it seems like it's related to [another open issue](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1121)).

Comment: Take a look at the [SuperZip shiny example](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/superzip-example.html), leaflet relies on zooming to your area of interest rather than "brushing" it. Cheers!